# Mongoid saving only ids and leaving out other fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri and mongoid in a test project.

Here's my code:

```
urls = Array[
  'http://www.example.com/cairo',
  'http://www.example.com/alexandria',
]

urls.each do |url|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  #Theater and location details here

  #movies scrapper starts here
  movies = doc.css('.itemContainer')

  movies.each do |movie|

  #movie title
  title = movie.css("h3.catItemTitle a").text

  #More code here    

  #movie synopsis
  synopsis = movie.css(".catItemIntroText p").text

  Movie.create! {
    {title: title}
    {synopsis: synopsis }
    #{movielength: movielength }
    #embedded theater collection
      {theaters: {theater: theater,
             address: address 
            }
        }
  }
 end   
end
```

My mongoid models look like this:

```
require 'mongoid'

class Movie
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, :type => String
  field :synopsis, :type => String

  attr_accessible :title, :synopsis

  embeds_many :theaters
end
```

When I run the Nokogiri script only the mongodb objectid gets saved and the field details are not created or saved.

Here's a sample of my database:

```
] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52be9b3c4cfad19f0c000011") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52be9b3c4cfad19f0c000012") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52be9b3c4cfad19f0c000013") }
has more
```

Everything works well using Ruby `puts` to output but saving in mongodb is a hassle. What am I doing wrong? I am using Mongoid (3.1.6) with Ruby 1.9.3p448 on Mac OS Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting the hashes. Do this instead for a starter:

```
Movie.create!(title: title, synopsis: synopsis, theaters: [theater])
```